# How can I identify if my code needs a Unit test a Kernel test or a browser test?

Tags: testing

In my project we extend base classes. BlockBase, ControllerBase, FormBase, FormatterBase and so on to build blocks, Fieldformatters, forms ...

We already have automated tests (functional) using a Testing automated framework based on Gherkin.

Since we are already running Functional tests, I understand there is no need to execute PHPUnit Functional,Browser, Kernel and Javascript scripts. Is my understanding correct?

If yes, what is left is Unit tests that extend the UnitTestCase class.
I cannot understand how to test with Unit tests my code that extends base class. I cannot understand and find examples of how I can unit test a Block Plugin, A field Formatter or a Controller that extends Controller base, renders an entity and generates a page.

Can I perform Unit tests on the above?